# How to Create email id for each user in Amazon Ec2?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, email-client

I am running my application in amazon Ec2 with PHP.We are using S3 for storage images and files.Now I want to create the email id for each user those who are successfully register.
      When the users send the mail from the another email id to this particular email id with attachment I need to get the files and upload to S3.

I read the [SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) document.But I didn't get any clue how to do this.Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to parse incoming email for attachments, if so take a look at the [imap functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) and [Mail_mimeDecode](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode/redirected), I use a combination of both.